# Is it impossible to have a @RequestParam as a List?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/selectTimeSpaceBusRunList.do")
public ModelAndView selectTimeSpaceBusRunList(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam("search_date") String search_date,
        @RequestParam(value="compid", required=false, defaultValue="") String compid,
        @RequestParam(value="routeid", required=true) String routeid,
        @RequestParam(value="busList", required=true) List<String> busList)
{
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    Map<String, List<TbDmhTmspaceChartVO>> resultMap = new HashMap<String, List<TbDmhTmspaceChartVO>>();

    try {
        TbDmhTmspaceChartVO vo = new TbDmhTmspaceChartVO();
        search_date = search_date.replaceAll("-", "");
        vo.setSearch_start_date(search_date + "000000");
        vo.setSearch_end_date(search_date + "235959");
        vo.setCompid(compid);
        vo.setRouteid(routeid);
        vo.setBusList(busList);
        List<TbDmhTmspaceChartVO> resultList = runService.selectTimeSpaceBusRunList(vo);
        resultMap.put("resultList", resultList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("##selectTimeSpaceBusRunList exception " + e.toString());
    }
    mv.addAllObjects(resultMap);
    mv.setViewName("jsonView");
    return mv;
}
```

And I have VO like this:

```
public class TbDmhTmspaceChartVO {
private String run_enddt;       //  date                yes     1   
private String busid;           //  number(9,0)         yes     2   
private String run_startdt;     //  date                yes     3   
private String routeid;         //  number(9,0)         yes     4   
private String compid;          //  number(6,0)         yes     5   
private String carregno;        //  varchar2(12 byte)   yes     6   
private String runord;          //  number(4,0)         yes     7   
private String start_pathseq;   //  number(5,0)         yes     8   
private String end_pathseq;     //  number(5,0)         yes     9   
private String total_bstopcnt;  //  number(10,0)        yes     10  
private String seq_list;        //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     11  
private String node_list;       //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     12  
private String hms_list;        //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     13  
private String coll_list;       //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     14  
private String cross_pass_cnt;  //  number(10,0)        yes     15  
private String seq_list_1;      //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     16  
private String node_list_1;     //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     17  
private String hms_list_1;      //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     18  
private String coll_list_1;     //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     19  
private String bstop_dep_cnt;   //  number(10,0)        yes     20  
private String seq_list_3;      //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     21  
private String node_list_3;     //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     22  
private String hms_list_3;      //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     23  
private String coll_list_3;     //  varchar2(4000 byte) yes     24  

private String search_start_date;
private String search_end_date;

private List<String> busList;

// getters and setters...
public List<String> getBusList() {
    return busList;
}
public void setBusList(List<String> busList) {
    this.busList = busList;
}
}
```

For the data I am sending is:

```
busList: ["7211342", "7015067"]
compid: "166001"
routeid: "165000056"
search_date: "2017-11-06"
```

My ajax Call is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./run/selectTimeSpaceBusRunList.do",
    data: {
        search_date : input_date,
        compid : $("#busCompany").val(),
        routeid : $("#busRoute").val(),
        busList : selected_bus_list
    },
    dataType : "json",
    beforeSend: null,
    success: success,
    error: null
});
```

When the ajax Call is done, it ends with error like this:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required List parameter 'busList' is not present
```

So there must be problem with `@RequestParam(value="busList", required=true) List<String> busList)`, but I could not find the solution with it.

My question is:

1. Is it impossible to get `List` variable with `@RequestParam`?
2. If it is impossible, is there other way to get `List` variable?
3. Is it possible to get DTO variable at once?

Regards,

---

**UPDATE**

I changed the `@RequestParam(value="busList", required=true) List<String> busList)` into `@RequestParam(value="busList", required=false) List<String> busList)`, and now it works fine. So I think the problem lies with `busList` not being sent in a right way.

Comment: Pass list like: `busList=A1&busList=A2` or `busList=A1,A2,A3`. You can also wrap all query parameter into a single class.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I'm sorry but where should I put that?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn is just saying from a request perspective, your AJAX call should be "formatting" the request as he is suggesting. In other words, he's saying it's possible, now you have to get your front end to pass in the list the correct way.

Comment: can you please check setter for busList

Comment: @ArunKumar I posted getters and setters above.

Comment: why use 
public void setBusList(String[] busList) {
    this.busList = busList;
}

instead of 

public void setBusList(List<String> busList) {
    this.busList = busList;
}

Comment: @ArunKumar Oh I changed the busList's type from List to String array while trying things to handle the problem. It was List when I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common & standard way to pass a list of values as URL parameters is to repeat them i.e.

http://rentacar.com/api/v1/search?make=audi&model=A8&type=6&type=11&type=12&color=RED&color=GREY

Now the question is to handle such input in Spring MVC REST endpoint? Lets assume you are developing a search api to find cars available to rent; this is how you will do it:

```
public List<Vehicle> search(@RequestParam(value="make", required=false) String make, @RequestParam(value="model", required=false) String model, @RequestParam(value="type", required=false) List<String> types, @RequestParam(value="color", required=false) List<String> colors) {
....
}
```

https://medium.com/@rasheedamir/spring-mvc-how-to-pass-list-of-values-as-url-parameters-5d57dcac8457

Comment: I did as the code you have written, but now it comes with error `org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required List parameter 'busList' is not present`.

Comment: Are you sure that URL which you are using for that call us correct?

Comment: Yes I am sure the URL is correct. I have a feeling that it may be because of the data I am sending. I am trying to send an array in Javascript and maybe it is wrong to get it as list in controller.

Comment: Have you used a debugger or logger to actually check URL assembled in your Javascript?

Comment: Yes, I checked the logger when I was writting this question.

Comment: Are you sending it as `busList=1&busList=2` or `busList=[1,2]`?

Comment: I am sending busList = [1, 2]

Comment: It should be like this `busList=1&busList=2` or `busList=1,2` without any brackets.

Comment: That was it! Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

As you are passing string values. You can use an array of busList like

```
http://localhost:8080/selectTimeSpaceBusRunList?busList=1,2,3&search_date=20120101&compid=123&routeid=someId
```

So controller endpoint will be like,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectTimeSpaceBusRunList") 
public void selectTimeSpaceBusRunList(@RequestParam("busList") String[] busList, @RequestParam("search_date") String search_date, @RequestParam("compid") String compid, @RequestParam("routeid") String routeid) {
   //Business logic here.
 }
```

Comment: Should `method = RequestMethod.GET` must exist?

Comment: not necessary, by default method is GET so not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?busList=A1,A2

```
 @PostMapping("/test")
 public void test(@RequestParam("busList") List<String> busList) {    
      System.out.println(busList); //[A1,A2]
 }
```

Comment: Is there any other solution beside this? I'm trying to work like my ajax call above.

Comment: then use @RequestBody for bus list

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to convert the array to a string of comma-separated items. Both `array.join(',')` and `array.toString()` are valid options.

Your updated AJAX call could look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./run/selectTimeSpaceBusRunList.do",
    data: {
        search_date : input_date,
        compid : $("#busCompany").val(),
        routeid : $("#busRoute").val(),
        busList : selected_bus_list.join(",")
    },
    dataType : "json",
    beforeSend: null,
    success: success,
    error: null
});
```

Note the line `bustList: selected_bus_list.join(",")`.